# Can Python automatically communicate with SVN

Tags: python, svn

I was hoping to implement an SVN communicator in my python program so that any file being worked on is automatically stored into the user's SVN account without any user interaction (username and password already provided so Python takes care of storage). Are there any libraries that can handle this kind of communication?

Answer (score 3):

There are [Python bindings for SVN](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/bindings/swig/INSTALL). They follow the C API, so present a fairly low-level interface, not very "Pythonic". I'm not sure how easy they are to install these days. I've tried to use it in the past, and found that it requires some digging into the C API documentation to figure out how to make it work.

[pysvn](http://pysvn.tigris.org/) provides a more "Pythonic" API. I've used this, and found it very simple in comparison.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [pysvn](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn.html) project, which provides python interface to various svn tasks. You could use that invoke the svn commit operation for the user action which you want to act upon.